# MAC bash commands stop working properly

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx

I was trying to install some stuff for scala development on my MAC, and probably I managed broke the shell/terminal while I was mindlessly running some scripts that I don't know.

Now when I start the terminal it always starts with this line;

```
$ /sbin:sbin:/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier
```

And now when I try, I see some bash commands does not work, for instance grep, syslog..etc I get an error saying;

```
-bash syslog: "no such file or directory"
```

Any idea what is wrong and how can I fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have an illegal space in the PATH variable assignment like so:

```
export PATH= /sbin:sbin:/usr/local/bin

# -bash: export: `/sbin:sbin:/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier

ls 

# -bash: ls: No such file or directory

# right way is to just drop the space
export PATH=/sbin:sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: tnx if so can I fix it in my .profile file?

Comment: yes! it was in bash profile file!